# Javascript <return>: undefined

Tags: javascript, return, undefined

I am trying to put canvas in iframe element with Javascript but when i execute code i got : undefined from debuger 
this is the code can someone help me?

```
function submitTryit() {
    var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifr.setAttribute("id", "iframeResult");
    document.getElementById("iframewrapper").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("iframewrapper").appendChild(ifr);

    canvas();
}

function canvas(){
    var ifrr = document.getElementById("iframeResult");
    var iframediv = (ifrr.contentWindow.document || ifrr.contentDocument.document);
    var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
    canv.setAttribute("id", "mycanvas");
    iframediv.body.appendChild(canv);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace, etc.

Comment: It would help others help you if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show us the relevant html for this page. What line of code does the debugger point to?

Comment: if iframediv is null then you get an undefined back. You should also provide the html to doublecheck if all is okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your code is fine, the issue is that you're running it too soon; you try to get `iframewrapper` before it even exists on the page. The solution is simple, don't call `submitTryIt()` until you're sure that the page has loaded

```
window.onload = function()
{
  submitTryit();
}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  submitTryit();
}

function submitTryit() {
  var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");
  ifr.setAttribute("id", "iframeResult");
  document.getElementById("iframewrapper").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("iframewrapper").appendChild(ifr);

  canvas();
}

function canvas() {
  var ifrr = document.getElementById("iframeResult");
  var iframediv = (ifrr.contentWindow.document || ifrr.contentDocument.document);
  var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
  canv.setAttribute("id", "mycanvas");
  iframediv.body.appendChild(canv);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="iframewrapper">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just for info you were right i just continue to write my function and everything was ok thank